# Running Access VBA sub from Batch

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, vba

I have about 8 Subs inside my access file that I would like to run externally from a batch file.

I have little experience with Batch so am not entirely sure where I start writing this, does anyone know if this is possible or could provide code that I could take a look at? I am struggling to find any info online.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score -1):

Google:
Access command line

Get, for example, this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207